# Unable to create environment with conda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to create an environment using `conda` but I'm getting the following error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - mkl==2019.0=118
>     - scipy==1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1 -> numpy[version='>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2019.3,<2020.0a0']
>   Use "conda search  --info" to see the dependencies for each package.

Is there a way to solve this problem?